# Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:11000

Tags: c#, tcp, tcp-ip

Клиент-серверное приложение на tcp/ip

Все работало на win xp(порты 11000  и 11001), но на win7 не стартует.

Итак:

1. Фаейрволл пробовали отключать;
2. В порты открытые пробовали подключать
3. Сервер запущен(другая программа - простенький клиент-сервер на tcp пашет),  а именно эта - нет

   ```
       // Устанавливаем для сокета локальную конечную точку
       IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
       IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
       IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
   ```

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто наведет на мысль буду очень признателен.
Проблема часто встречается, но решения никто так и не дал

Comment: Сервер, слушающий порт 11000, точно-преточно запущен?

Comment: Ощущение, что сервер слушает по IPv4, а клиент пытается по IPv6 подключиться. Попробуйте для проверки на сетевой карточке временно отключить IPv6.

Comment: @ГеннадийП зачем так сложно-то?

Comment: Чего скажет `netstat -a -n`?

Comment: 1. Отключение ipv6 не помогло. 2. netstat -a -n -- а что там нужно увидеть? открытые порты?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вы используете Dns для того чтобы преобразовать 127.0.0.1 в ip-адрес? По-проще-то способа вы не нашли?

Для начала, у класса `IPAddress` есть замечательный метод [`Parse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_IPAddress_Parse_System_String_):

```
IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
```

Кроме того, в этом классе есть статическое поле [`Loopback`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.loopback?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Loopback;
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что автор использует DNS не для преобразования 127.0.0.1 в IP-адрес, а как костыльный способ определить "свой IP-адрес" (и не учитывает, что у компьютера их несколько).

Answer (score -2):

Тебе нужно начать приём данных.

> Private Sub Getfile()
>          listener1 = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 27020)
>          listener1.Start()
>          While True
>              Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient()
>              client = listener1.AcceptTcpClient()
>              Dim Stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
>              Dim reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(Stream)
>              Dim fileLength As Integer = reader.ReadInt32
>              Dim fileData() As Byte = reader.ReadBytes(fileLength)
>              Dim Str As String = Encoding.Default.GetString(fileData)
>              STR1 = Str
>          End While
>      End Sub

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Th = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Getfile)
    Th.Start()
End Sub
```

VB синтаксис.